# VBA: Zip file out put rename

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm trying to rename the output of my file when I unzip. I have tried renameing to `test.xls` But it throws a object variable not set error. Is there another way other then scanning `.datecreated` on all the files in the folder? If there is a way to rename the file on unzip that would be best.

```
Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    oApp.NameSpace("C:\Users\**\Downloads\TempFolder\test.xls").CopyHere oApp.NameSpace("C:\Users\**\Downloads\TempFolder\testzip.zip").Items
Set oApp = Nothing
```

Comment: Copy the file first, without changing the file extension, then change the file name.

Comment: What is inside `testzip.zip` - a single file or multiple files? If multiple, do you want to extract them all?

Comment: @Andre there will allways be just one file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `CopyHere` method is only valid for **folder** objects (this includes zip files when zipping), not for regular files. Hence the error message.

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787866(v=vs.85).aspx) or [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_files_zip.php#CopyHereUNZIP) .

I would extract the zip to a folder that is guaranteed to be **empty**.
Then move the (single) file to your actual target folder, renaming it in the process.

```
Const Zipfile = "C:\Users\**\Downloads\TempFolder\testzip.zip"
Const EmptyFolder = "C:\Users\**\Downloads\EmptyFolder"
Const TargetFolder = "C:\Users\**\Target"
Dim strFile As String

Set oApp = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
' Unzip into empty folder
oApp.NameSpace(EmptyFolder).CopyHere oApp.NameSpace(Zipfile).Items
Set oApp = Nothing

' Get first and only file
strFile = Dir(EmptyFolder & "\*.*")
' Move and rename
Name EmptyFolder & "\" & strFile As TargetFolder & "\test.xls"
```