# Show Windows File Copy Progress Bar in Access-VBA (2016)

Tags: ms-access, vba

Copying many files from several sources to several destination over our network using MS Access 2016. Can use SysCmd to show Progress Bar on status Bar. Can also show file copy counter as a msg on status bar via Application.Echo True, "msg". But neither is as informative or visually appealing as that used by Windows file copy progress bar. Have looked at several customized progress bars on forms. If I could develop each to show the same information and progress bar as the one used by Windows, it'd be fine. But I wonder if there's a way to call the one used in Windows from MS Access VBA. Thank you in advance.

Comment: To show the windows progress bar, you can use `Shell.Folder.CopyHere`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44737108/vba-zip-file-out-put-rename - but it will be one call per destination folder, not one overall progress bar.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the only way to achieve this is to create a custom COM library. Because the explanation is rather long, I will refer you to some resources (you will need some version of Visual Studio to create the library, and some experience with either C# or VB.Net).

You will want to call `FileSystem.CopyFile` in your library, with `ShowUI` set to `AllDialogs` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms127965(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb).

See http://www.geeksengine.com/article/create-dll.html for instructions how to create the library, and register it in Access.